# SQL Server Query with Multiple Where Clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I hope you might be able to help. I'm trying to write a SQL query which requires 2 where conditions. This is what I've come up with but getting errors:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (Datediff(dd,TimeStampUTC,dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())))
AND (MeterTagId Between 416 AND 462)
```

Essentially I have a table with data being collected every 15 minutes for a range of tags. What I'm trying to do is return "Previous Days" data for a range of tags.

Any help you can give would be extremely appreciated as my SQL knowledge is still quite limited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jyparask ... already removed my comment - I errornuously assumed MySql - wasn't looking properly ;-) ... and added the sqlserver-tag to the post after that!

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a condition here:

```
WHERE (Datediff(dd,TimeStampUTC,dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())))
```

You need to add an = or <= or >= or < or > or between or something that will provide true or false

This seems ok:

```
AND (MeterTagId Between 416 AND 462)
```

Please also post your errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an index on `TimeStampUTC`, then you should try to do this with no functions on that column:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE TimeStampUTC between cast(getdate() - 1 as date) and cast(getdate() as date) and
      MeterTagId Between 416 AND 462;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff, this worked a treat. Really appreciate everyones responses.